# Is it possible to define a default.xml layout in a custom module but only affects the default.xml of that module?

Tags: magento2, layout

For example:

I have a custom module Vendor_Name in which I want to remove certain blocks but only for all the layouts of the Magento_Customer module so I do not have to create 4 5 layouts to remove the same blocks but I need them somewhere else. I mean, remove top.search block in the customer/login, customer/lougout, customer/forgotpassword layouts and so on but keep them in catalog/view for example, all within a module to easy deploy, just install the module and I have the blocks removed as I want it.

I guess I can put a default.xml in my `app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/Magento_Customer/layout/default.xml` but I do not want to do it in a theme, it is possible to do the same but from a custom module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you should use `default.xml` in this case. Instead, to perform your task, just modify `app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/Magento_Customer/layout/customer_account.xml` if you want to remove `top.search` block on **any** customer pages.

One more case, if you just want to show `top.search` block on specific page, you can remove it on `default.xml`. Then add `top.search` block back on the specific layout file.

And, it's not a good idea to put core layout file into a module.

Comment: Ok i see, i like the idea of ` just modify app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/Magento_Customer/layout/customer_account.xml if you want to remove top.search block on any customer pages.` Did not know that creating a customer_account.xml layout it affects all subsequents layout of that module